# To show that a function is not of bounded variation on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

What would be a sequence of partitions of [0,1] to show that the function

$f(x)$ = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x$ $\in$[0,1]$\cap$$Q^c$} \\
-x, & \text{if $x$$\in$[0,1]$\cap$$Q$}
\end{cases}

is not of bounded variation on [0,1]?

Comment: Alternate between rational and irrational points.

Comment: It is a variation at least $1/2$ between rational and irrational points for $x\ge 1/2$, and there are infintely many such changes in this part of the interval.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you. It works.

Answer (score -1):

Try partition

$x_n    = \frac{1}{n}$ , if $n$ is odd

$=\frac{1}{n+n^\frac{1}{n}}$ , if n is even.

Comment: The site supports latex, write `$5\cdot5$` and you get $5\cdot 5$.